# Solving $\sqrt{a +\sqrt{a-x}}+\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a+x}}=2x, \ a\in\Bbb{R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, radicals

> Given
>   $$\sqrt{a +\sqrt{a-x}}+\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a+x}}=2x$$
>   and $a\in\Bbb{R}$, express $x$ in terms of $a$.

I rationalised the above expression and then again rationalised which gave me :

$$\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a-x}}-\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a+x}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+x}-\sqrt{a-x}}$$

Now, what should I do?

If didn't rationalised the original Equation, or if the squared both sides twice then too bi-quadratic or higher degree polynomial will be obtained.

What should be done?

Comment: Do you mean $$\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a-x}}+\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a+x}}=2x$$?

Comment: Yes  Exactly thats it

Comment: And what denotes $a$ here, a Parameter?

Comment: Yes , a belongs to parameter and have to find x in terms of a :

Comment: Any reason to imagine it has a particularly sensible answer?  For $a=2,3$ the answers look fairly random (though of course that might not mean much).

Comment: Check graph of that expression , we will find that x is dependent on √a like term and gives solution at approx a >=1.2

Comment: Where did you find this question btw? Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2563567/heuristics-when-doing-heavy-algebraic-manipulation-sqrta-sqrtax-x

Comment: We need a clear statement. Is $a>0$ or is it possible to have also $a=-2018$? In case $a$ is positive: The solutions of the equation are searched in $\Bbb R$ or in $\Bbb C$?

Comment: The solutions of equation are to be searched in R.

Comment: Full version. Explicit closed solution, detalized checking

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simplification, which leads to a parametrized solution.

Write the original equation as two equations
$$
\sqrt{a +\sqrt{a-x}} = x +q\\
\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a+x}}= x -q
$$
where $q$ is a function of $a$. 
Double squaring both equations gives
$$
(x+q)^4-2a(x+q)^2+x+a^2-a = 0 \\ 
(x-q)^4-2a(x-q)^2-x+a^2-a = 0
$$ 
Subtracting and adding gives the two equations
$$
x^2+q^2-a -\frac{1}{4q}= 0 \\ 
x^4+ 6 q^2x^2 + q^4-2a(x^2+q^2)+a^2-a = 0
$$
The first equation gives the result 
$$
x = \sqrt{-q^2+a +\frac{1}{4q}}= \sqrt{a + f(q)}
$$ 
with the offset $f(q)$. In here, $q$ has to be inserted, where $q = q(a)$ is obtained by replacing all terms with $x^2$ in  the second equation with the first equation, giving
$$
(-q^2+a +\frac{1}{4q})^2+ 6 q^2(-q^2+a +\frac{1}{4q}) + q^4-2a(a +\frac{1}{4q})+a^2-a = 0
$$ 
Expanding this expression gives an implicit formula for $q(a)$ as follows:
$$
- 64 q^6 + 64 a q^4 + 16 q^3 - 16 a q^2 + 1 = 0
$$
I wasn't able to solve this further for $q$. However, the equations directly lead to a parametrized solution. Let $q$ be a free parameter. The range where $q$ is to be chosen from is discussed below. Then for each $q$, we have $a$ and $x$ according to
$$
a  = \frac{64 q^6 - 16 q^3 - 1}{64 q^4 - 16 q^2} \\
x = \sqrt{-q^2+a +\frac{1}{4q}}
$$

The following observations can be made:

For large $a$, the equation for $a$ gives $q^2 \to \frac{1}{4}$. This can also be observed by regarding the very first set of two equations and treating $q$ as a small disturbance, which can in first order be neglected if all other terms grow exceedingly large. We then have 
$$
\sqrt{a +\sqrt{a-x_1}} = x_1\\
\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a+x_2}}= x_2
$$
which are solved (see [Solve the equation: $x=\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a+x}},(a\geq 1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1926750/)) by
$$
x_1 = \frac12 + \sqrt{a -3/4}\\
x_2 = -\frac12 + \sqrt{a -3/4}
$$
So indeed, the $x_{1,2}$ grow exceedingly large, and $q = -\frac12$ gives both the correct offset term $-\frac34$ under the previous root $
x = \sqrt{-q^2+a +\frac{1}{4q}}
$, as well as the two deviations $x - x_{1,2}$. For small $a$, correction terms  must be added to $q(a)$ (in the sense of an expansion).

---

*Addendum:*
1. As a side observation, one can use the two solutions $x_{1,2}$ to establish that the modified equation
$$
\sqrt{a +\sqrt{a-x -\frac12}}+\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a+x-\frac12}}=2x
$$
is solved by $x = \sqrt{a -3/4}$.

2. Note that in the general solution $x =\sqrt{a + f(q)}$, the offset $f(q) = -q^2 +\frac{1}{4q}$ actually has a maximum at $q = -0.5$. This can be seen by
   $f'(q)  =  \frac{-1 - 8 q^3}{4 q^2}$ which is zero at $q = -0.5$. Hence, the offset has its maximum $f(q= -0.5) = -0.75$ for $\alpha \to \infty$. It will be lower for other $q$. The behavior of $q(a)$ is given in the following plot. For low $a=1.5$, for example, we have $q\simeq -0.81$ and $f(q) \simeq -0.965$. The plot $q(a)$, together with the offset behavior $f(q)$, establish that the offset is monotonously rising with $a$ in a small range of $f$-values.

[image: q(a)]

Comment: well, but .. actually $q$ cannot be negative, so there is something that I do not grasp in your solution

Comment: @GCab Can you elaborate why $q$ cannot become negative?

Comment: for the expression to be real we must have
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le a - x \hfill \cr 
  0 \le a + x \hfill \cr 
  0 \le a + \sqrt {a - x}  \hfill \cr 
  0 \le a - \sqrt {a + x}  \hfill \cr 
  0 \le x \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le x \le a \hfill \cr 
  0 \le a \hfill \cr 
  x \le a\left( {a - 1} \right) \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
and
$$
\sqrt {a + \sqrt {a - x} }  - \sqrt {a - \sqrt {a + x} }  = 2q
$$
and since the either $a$ and the sq. r.  must be non-neg., the $\sqrt{a-\dots} \le \sqrt{a+\cdots}$ then $0 \le q$

Comment: @GCab We can obtain a lot of possible solutions, but the constraints allow only the homogenious one.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: sorry, do not get what you mean

Comment: @GCab I've written this in my answer.

Comment: @Andreas: I could check that in your parametric equation you ended up in reversing (don't know how) the sign of $q$. It shall be: $$
\left\{ \matrix{
  a = {{64q^{\,6}  + 16q^{\,3}  - 1} \over {64q^{\,4}  - 16q^{\,2} }} \hfill \cr 
  \;x^{\,2}  = a - {{4q^{\,3}  + 1} \over {4q}} \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
after which you get correct solutions for $1/2 < q$

Comment: @GCab Thanks. I carefully checked my equations and  found them ok. I also performed some number crunching (Matlab double precision) for the  parametric solution and it matches the OPs original equation up to $\cal O (e^{-16})$. So I cannot see errors.

Comment: @Andreas: I investigated a bit on our two approaches: a) our sets of parametric equations $a(q),\,x(q)$ differ only in the sign of $q$ , if you plot them you can see what happens b) although for different ranges of $q$, finally they **provide the same set of solutions (a,x)**  .  So never mind

Answer (score 3):

---

$\color{brown}{\mathbf{\text{Reformulation of the problem.}}}$

At first, let us try to find any solution, using substitutions 
$$y=\sqrt{a+x},\quad z=\sqrt{a-x},\tag1$$
then
$$x=y^2-a=a-z^2,\quad a \ge 0,\quad x\ge 0,\tag2$$
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{a-y}+\sqrt{a+z} = y^2-z^2\\
y^2+z^2=2a\\
0\le z\le \sqrt a \le y,\tag3
\end{cases}
Let

> $$u=\sqrt{a-y}=\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a+x}},\quad v=\sqrt{a+z} = \sqrt{a+\sqrt{a-x}},\tag4$$

then
$$y=a-u^2,\quad z=v^2-a,\quad x=(a-u^2)^2-a=a-(v^2-a)^2,\tag5$$
\begin{cases}
u+v=(a-u^2)^2-(v^2-a)^2\\
(a-u^2)^2+(v^2-a)^2=2a\\
0\le v^2-a\le \sqrt a\le a-u^2\\
0\le u\le \sqrt a\le v,
\end{cases}
or
\begin{cases}
u+v=(v^2-u^2)(2a-u^2-v^2)\\
u^4+v^4 -2a(u^2+v^2+1)+2a^2=0\\
0\le u\le\sqrt{a-\sqrt a}\\
\sqrt a\le v \le \sqrt{a+\sqrt a}.
\end{cases}
Solution $\mathbf{u+v=0}\ $ exists only if $\mathbf{a=0\Rightarrow x=0}.$

Solution $\mathbf{u+v\not=0}\ $ exists only if $\mathbf{a\ge1}$ and can be obtained from the system
\begin{cases}
(v-u)(2a-u^2-v^2)=1\\
2(u^4+v^4) - 4a(u^2+v^2+1) + 4a^2=0\\
0\le u\le\sqrt{a-\sqrt a}\\
\sqrt a\le v \le \sqrt{a+\sqrt a}.\tag6
\end{cases}
wherein $\mathbf{u < v}.$

Taking in account the identity
$$(2a-u^2-v^2)^2 = 4a^2 - 4a(u^2+v^2) + u^4 + v^4 + 2u^2v^2,$$
one can get the system
\begin{cases}
(v-u)(2a-u^2-v^2)=1\\
(2a-u^2-v^2)^2 + (u^2-v^2)^2 - 4a = 0\\
0\le u\le\sqrt{a-\sqrt a}\\
\sqrt a\le v \le \sqrt{a+\sqrt a},
\end{cases}
or
\begin{cases}
(v-u)(2a-u^2-v^2)=1\\
(v-u)^2((u^2-v^2)^2 - 4a) + 1=0\\
0\le u\le\sqrt{a-\sqrt a}\\
\sqrt a\le v \le \sqrt{a+\sqrt a}.\tag7
\end{cases}
Then
\begin{align}
&(u^2-v^2)^2= (v-u)^2(u+v)^2= (v-u)^2\biggl(2(u^2+v^2)-(v-u)^2\biggr)\\
&=(v-u)^2\biggl(2\left(2a-\dfrac1{v-u}\right)-(v-u)^2\biggr)\\
&=-(v-u)^4+4a(v-u)^2 - 2(v-u),\\
\end{align}

> \begin{cases}
> (v-u)^6-4a(v-u)^4 + 2(v-u)^3 + 4a(v-u)^2 - 1=0\\
> u^2+v^2=2a - \dfrac1{v-u}\\
> 0\le u\le\sqrt{a-\sqrt a}\\
> \sqrt a\le v \le \sqrt{a+\sqrt a}.\tag8
> \end{cases}

---

$\color{brown}{\mathbf{\text{Getting of the possible solutions.}}}$

Formulas $(8)$ allow to get values $v-u = s$ and $u^2+v^2=2a-\dfrac1s$ by the given $a.$

The equation 
$$s^6 - 4as^4 + 2s^3 + 4as^2 - 1 = 0\tag9$$
can be solved, using the form of
$$s^3 - \dfrac1{s^3} - 4a\left(s-\dfrac1s\right) + 2 = 0,$$
or
$$4t^3+(3-4a)t-1 = 0,\tag{10}$$
where
$$t=\dfrac12\left(\dfrac1s - s\right).$$
This gives [the simple real solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4t%5E3%2B(3-4a)t-1%3D0)

> $$t = \dfrac12\left(\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{1+\left(1-\dfrac43a\right)^3}+1} +
> \dfrac{\dfrac43a-1}{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{1+\left(1-\dfrac43a\right)^3}+1}}\right),\quad \mathbf{a\le\dfrac32}. \tag{11}$$

If $\mathbf{a>\dfrac32},$ then, using [Chebyshev Polynomial of the First Kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html),
\begin{align}
&4\left(\dfrac t{\sqrt{\dfrac43a-1}}\right)^3 - 3\left(\dfrac t{\sqrt{\dfrac43a-1}}\right) = \dfrac 1{\left(\sqrt{\dfrac43a-1}\right)^3},\\
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&\cos\left(3\arccos\left(\dfrac t{\sqrt{\dfrac43a-1}}\right)\right) = \dfrac 1{\left(\sqrt{\dfrac43a-1}\right)^3},
\end{align}

> $$t = \sqrt{\dfrac43a-1}\cos\left(\dfrac{2k}3\pi 
> + \dfrac13\arccos\dfrac1{\left(\sqrt{\dfrac43a-1}\right)^3}\right),
> \quad \mathbf{a>\dfrac32},\tag{12}$$

where $k=0,1,2$ is the branch number.
That leads to the system
$$\begin{cases}
v - u = \sqrt{t^2+1}-t\\
u^2 + v^2 = 2a - \sqrt{t^2+1} - t.
\end{cases}\tag{13}$$
At the same time,
$$x=\dfrac{u+v}2 = \dfrac12\sqrt{2(u^2+v^2)-(v-u)^2}.$$
Therefore,

> $$x = \dfrac12\sqrt{4a-2\sqrt{t^2+1}-2t-(\sqrt{t^2+1}-t)^2},\tag{14}$$

where $t$ is given by $(11),(12).$

---

$\color{brown}{\mathbf{\text{Solutions analysis.}}}$

Note that
\begin{align}
&\sqrt{a\mp x}=\sqrt a\sqrt{1\mp\dfrac xa}\ge \sqrt a\left(1\mp\dfrac x{2a}\right) = \sqrt a\mp\dfrac x{2\sqrt a}, \\[4pt]
&\sqrt{a\pm\sqrt{a\mp x}} \ge \sqrt{a\pm\sqrt a - \dfrac x{2\sqrt a}} = \sqrt{a\pm\sqrt a}\sqrt{1-\dfrac x{2\sqrt a\left(a\pm\sqrt a\right)}}\\[4pt]
&\ge \sqrt{a\pm\sqrt a}\left(1-\dfrac x{4\sqrt a\left(a\pm\sqrt a\right)}\right) = \sqrt{a\pm\sqrt a}-\dfrac x{4\sqrt a\sqrt{a\pm\sqrt a}},\\
&\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a-x}}+\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a+x}} \ge \sqrt{a+\sqrt a}+\sqrt{a-\sqrt a} - \dfrac x{4\sqrt a\sqrt{a-\sqrt a}\sqrt{a+\sqrt a}}\left(\sqrt{a+\sqrt a}+\sqrt{a-\sqrt a}\right) = \sqrt{2\left(a+\sqrt{a-a^2}\right)}\left(1-\dfrac x{4a\sqrt{a-1}}\right),\\
\end{align}
$$\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a-x}}+\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a+x}} \ge \sqrt{2\left(a+\sqrt{a-a^2}\right)}\left(1-\dfrac x{4a\sqrt{a-1}}\right),\tag{15}$$
so the real solutions of the issue equation can exist only if
$$1-\dfrac x{4a\sqrt{a-1}} \le\dfrac {2x}{\sqrt{2\left(a+\sqrt{a-a^2}\right)}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2(a-\sqrt{a^2-a})}}{\sqrt a}x ,$$
or only in the case

> $$x\ge B(a),\quad B(a)=\dfrac{4a\sqrt{a-1}}{1+4\sqrt{2(a^2-a)(a-\sqrt{a-a^2})}}\tag{16}$$

(see also [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%5Cdfrac%7B4a%5Csqrt%7Ba-1%7D%7D%7B1%2B4%5Csqrt%7B2(a%5E2-a)(a-%5Csqrt(a%5E2-a))%7D%7D+where+a+in+(0,+16)))

[image: Solutions Analysis]

This means that solutions with $\mathbf{a<1}$ doesn't exist.

If $\mathbf{a\in\left[1,\dfrac32\right]},$ then solutions also doesn't exist.
In particular, for $a=\dfrac32\quad B(a)>0.86.$ On the other hand, equation $(10)$ takes form of
$$t^3-3t-1=0, \quad (t-1)(2t+1)^2=0,\quad t \in\{-1/2, 1\},\quad x \in\{\approx 0.732, 1/2\},$$
and this contradicts with $(16).$

Let us consider the case $\mathbf{a>\dfrac32}.$

If $\mathbf{k=0}$ (zero branch), then formula $(12)$ means that
$$t\ge \sqrt{\dfrac43a-1}\dfrac{\sqrt3}2 = \sqrt{a-\dfrac34},$$
and one can check that $x(a)< B(a)$ (see also [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%5Cdfrac%7B4a%5Csqrt%7Ba-1%7D%7D%7B1%2B4%5Csqrt%7B2(a%5E2-a)(a-%5Csqrt(a%5E2-a))%7D%7D,1%2F2%5Csqrt(4a-2(%5Csqrt%20(x%5E2%2B1)%2Bx)%20-%20(%5Csqrt%20(x%5E2%2B1)-x)%5E2)%7D,%20where%20x%20%3D%20sqrt(a-3%2F4))).

If $\mathbf{k=1}$ (the first branch), then, using $(12),$
$$t\le -\sqrt{\dfrac43a-1}\dfrac{\sqrt3}2 = -\sqrt{a-\dfrac34},$$
and $x(a)<B(a)$ again (see also [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%5Cdfrac%7B4a%5Csqrt%7Ba-1%7D%7D%7B1%2B4%5Csqrt%7B2(a%5E2-a)(a-%5Csqrt(a%5E2-a))%7D%7D,1%2F2%5Csqrt(4a-2(%5Csqrt%20(x%5E2%2B1)%2Bx)%20-%20(%5Csqrt%20(x%5E2%2B1)-x)%5E2)%7D,%20where%20x%20%3D%20-sqrt(a-3%2F4))).

If $\mathbf{k=2}$ (the second branch), then verification, using MathCad, leads to the positive result.

[image: Final Verification]

Therefore, all solutions $x$ of the issue equation can be defined by formula $(14),$ where

> $$t=-\sqrt{\dfrac{4a-3}3}\sin\left(\dfrac13\arcsin\dfrac{3\sqrt3}{(4a-3)\sqrt{4a-3}}\right).\tag{17}$$

Gratitude to [GCab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/317234/g-cab) to the solution example.

Comment: your entry statement is **not correct**: e.g.: $a=4 \; x=1.8015..$ is a solution

Comment: @GCab You are right (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(4x-sqrt(5x))%2Bsqrt(4x%2Bsqrt(3x))%3D2x), thanks.

Comment: @GCab Fixed. Waiting for comments.

Comment: Oh.. nice work indeed ! I did not get through the detail of calculations, but sure you checked the results, so (+1).  I was also expecting trig to be somehow involved .. so I do appreciate that you have been able to find a relation with Chebyshev P. .

Comment: @GCab About Pafnutii Lvovich, you can see there:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1823096/limit-of-the-solutions-of-a-trigonometric-equation/1829648#1829648 and there: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240145/how-to-integrate-int-frac-cosm-x-cos-nx-mathrmdx/2246044#2246044

Comment: @GCab And that: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1907088/how-to-prove-frac-arccos-frac-sqrt36-pi-is-not-a-rational-number/1907160#1907160

Comment: interesting links, many thanks

Comment: @GCab Somewhere DSP was my profession.

Comment: @GCab [Chebyshev again](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3026238/compute-int-frac1-beta-1-cdot-e-gammam-cdot-t-e-gamma-cdot-t/3064637#3064637)

Answer (score -2):

Squaring both sides, $$a\require{\cancel}\cancel{+\sqrt{a-x}}+a\cancel{-\sqrt{a-x}}+2\sqrt{\left(a+\sqrt{a-x}\right)\left(a-\sqrt{a-x}\right)}=2\left(a+\sqrt{a^2-a+x}\right)=4x^2.$$ since for all $m,n$ one has that $(m+n)(m-n)=m^2-n^2$. Now, dividing both sides by $2$,$$\begin{align} a+\sqrt{a^2-a+x}&=2x^2 \\ \Leftrightarrow (2x^2-a)^2 &= 4x^4 + a^2 - 4ax^2 \\ &= a^2 - a + x.\end{align}$$ Cancel out the term $a^2$ from both sides and expanding,$$4x^2(x^2-a) = x-a.$$ Now, notice that $$\frac{x^2-a}{x-a} = \frac{x^2-a+x-x}{x-a} = \frac{x^2-x}{x-a}+1.$$ Therefore, $$\begin{align}4x^2\left(\frac{x^2-a}{x-a}\right)= 4x^2\left(\frac{x^2-x}{x-a}+1\right)&=1 \\ \Leftrightarrow \frac{4x^3(x-1)}{x-a}+4x^2&=1.\end{align}$$ Now, since $4x^2 = (2x)^2$ then converting it to that and subtracting $1$ from both sides, $$\begin{align} \frac{4x^3(x-1)}{x-a} + (2x+1)(2x-1)&=0 \\ \Leftrightarrow \frac{4x^3(x-1)}{x-a} + x(2x+1) + (x-1)(2x+1) &= 0 \\ \Leftrightarrow (x-1)\left(\frac{4x^3}{x-a} + (2x+1)(x+1)\right)&=0.\end{align}$$ Solve for $x$ and $a$. To start you off, $x=1$.

Comment: Your First step is incorrect as One term is √(a+x) and other term is √(a-x)  How can you cancel these terms.

Comment: @Doraemon oh my mistake. Thank you for picking that up! I had thought otherwise... one thing I hate about math is that when you stuff up one step, every other step following from that is wrong too, no matter how many you've done, hahah